# Open a java desktop application while saving a Microsoft word document using ActiveX control in java

Tags: java, vba, swing, jacob, activex-documents

I am trying to open a java Desktop application(call it MyApplication.jar file written in Swing). I can open this java application using VBA macros code.

I want to open it saving the word document. means when user press save it should not allowed to save the word but open  the MyApplication.jar(My desktop application) in which user can fill some meta data about the document and after that user can save the document.

I tried [Jacob](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33305) library which use ActiveX Control in java to interact with word document but I want to open my desktop java application while saving the document.

I am unable to find some good example/library to do the same.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not clear. Do you mean that when MS Word goes to save a Word document, you want to pop your application? If so, I hope you don't achieve that, it would be most intrusive.

Comment: when MS Word goes to save a Word document, you want to pop your application. Exactly this is what I am looking for

Comment: My application will be used by clients who are trusting us because they need to enable their ActiveX control to use our application